# Checkbox are getting unchecked if they are of same ng-model AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

i have a scenario.

suppose i do have two pages view 1 and view 2.
and i have three values A,B,C by which i can compare the checkbox on both views.

now on view 1 there is a checkbox with value A,B,C.
and on view 2 there are values "A,B,C" , "A,B,C1" , "A,B,C2".

these values are bind with checkbox on both views.
 means on view 1 there is a checkbox with value A,B,C and if we click on button against that checkbox it will show us the multiple values on view 2.

i have put same ng-model for both checkbox lists.
so that if i click on view one then the c on view will be check on view 2 also.

but if i uncheck c valued checkbox on view 2 then the checkbox of view 1 is also unchecked. and user think that nothing is seleted.
i want to show something on that inner values are checked for that checkbox on view 1.

is there any solution to this? i am using ionic, AngularJS

Please help
thank you.

Comment: we need some code, it's a mess trying to understand your "scenario"

Comment: put some code or plunker in there... I cant understand what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: ok will provide as much as i can.

Comment: I don't really understand the question nor the example - a working plunker (with Angular und JS objects) would help. - Maybe you are looking for **indeterminate-checkbox** ? [See](http://jsfiddle.net/cjwprostar/M4vGj/6/)